# Simple file upload without using asp.net fileupload control

Tags: c#, file-upload

I have an html page and I want to upload a file usign the basic html input file without using the asp.net fileupload control.
I tried to write the following code in the html page and redirect it to the home page
(aspx page)

```
<form action ="../../default.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="myform">

                <input id="upload_file" type="file" />
                <input id="sumbit_button" type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

but the Request.Files does not contain the upload_file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately I did not get any answer, I solved it by using aspx file instead of html